# Integral Gronwall Estimate for Operators.

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, integral-inequality

Consider a (possibly unbounded) densely defined selfadjoint operator $A$ on $\mathcal{D}(A) \subset C(\Omega)$ for some domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with spectrum $\sigma(A) \le \lambda$ for some fixed $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}.$ Suppose it generates a semigroup $S(t)$. Suppose I have the bound
$$
0 \le u(t, x) \le  f(t,x) + \int_0^t Au(s, x) \ ds, t \in[0, T],
$$

for some $f \ge 0.$ Can we find an **integral** Gronwall-type bound for $u?$
My naive expectation would be something like the following (but I believe it would be wrong):
$$
u(t,x) \le f(t,x) +\int_0^tf(s,x) \lambda e^{\lambda(t-s)} \ ds
$$
The differential inequality should be simply comparison:
$$
\dot{u} \le Au + f , u(0) = u_0 \ \ \Rightarrow  u \le v \text{ with }  \ \ \dot{v} = Av + f, v(0) = v_0
$$
which follows from $S(\tau)h(s,x) \ge 0, \forall h \ge 0.$

Any "integral" estimate or useful counterexample is welcome, also if you need to add some hypotheis.